# PowerMockito verifyNew and verifyPrivate are mutually exclusive?

Tags: spring, mockito, powermockito

I have a class like this

```
@Component  
public class TestClass {

  public void testMethod(){
      FinalClass f = new FinalClass("string");
      somePrivateMethod(f.getSomeString());
  }

  private void somePrivateMethod(String s){

  }
}
```

As you can see it has a public method and private method. In public method it is instantiating an instance of FinalClass, which is a class in some third party library and it is final. Lets say it is like this

```
public final class FinalClass {

  private final String someString;

  public FinalClass(final String s) {
    someString = s;
  }

  public String getSomeString() {
    return someString;
  }
}
```

And Now I am writing unit test for my test class. Since I have to verify final classes and private methods, I am using powermockito. And this is how my test class looks like

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({TestClass.class, FinalClass.class})
public class TestClassTest {

  private TestClass testClass;
  private FinalClass finalClass;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    finalClass = PowerMockito.mock(FinalClass.class);
    testClass = spy(new TestClass());
  }

  @Test
  public void testSomething() throws Exception {
    whenNew(FinalClass.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(finalClass);

    testClass.testMethod();
    verifyNew(FinalClass.class);
    //verifyPrivate(testClass).invoke("testMethod");
  }
}
```

It works fine. But the problem is the last two statements verifyNew and verifyPrivate are working mutually exclusively. I mean when I comment one of those(doesn't matter which), the test passes. But when both are enabled, the test fails
Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?